# Making a GET request in R

Tags: r, http, rcurl, httr

I've been playing a little with httr and rcurl and cannot manage to translate the following curl GET request into R:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 31232187asdsadh23187' 'https://this.url.api.com:334/api/endpoint'
```

Particularly, I've been having some trouble to pass the Authorization option as I was not able to find the equivalent parameter in neither of the libraries. It might be a custom header maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the new and further improving curlconverter package.  It will take a curl request and output an httr command.

```
#devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/curlconverter")

library(curlconverter)

curlExample <- "curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 31232187asdsadh23187' 'https://this.url.api.com:334/api/endpoint'"

resp <- make_req(straighten(curlExample))
resp
```

Comment: this library is so cool! What has been your experience with it? do you always get good working curl conversions?

Comment: It is definitely a package that I foresee getting a lot of use.  It is fairly new but I find it quite easy to pop in my curl requests and get a good chunk of httr code that I can use.

Answer (score 9):

```
httr::GET('https://this.url.api.com:334/api/endpoint', 
      accept_json(), 
      add_headers('Authorization' = 'Bearer 31232187asdsadh23187'))
```

See also https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter

Comment: The curl converter is really cool! I will be trying this tomorrow and will get back to you to let you know whether it worked!

Comment: sorry it took some time to get back to you. This request worked! although the curl converter that JackStat suggested makes making requests in R a piece of cake!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sckott answer. I don't know too much about the maintenance and officiallity of curlconverter, but to complete [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) function i will add few lines more.

```
getInfoInJson <- httr::GET('https://this.url.api.com:334/api/endpoint', 
      accept_json(), 
      add_headers('Authorization' = 'Bearer 31232187asdsadh23187'))

 #safe the info in a json object 
 jsonInfoImg <- content(getInfoInJson, type="application/json")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [httr2](https://httr2.r-lib.org/reference/curl_translate.html) package (a rewrite of httr) has the `curl_translate` function which takes a curl command generated from [copy as curl](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/copyas) in a browser's developer tools and translates it into a httr2 request. It is influenced by the `curlconverter` function cited in other answers.

```
resp <- 
  request("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559913/making-a-get-request-in-r") |> 
  req_headers(
    `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0",
    Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate, br",
    `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` = "1",
    DNT = "1",
    `Sec-GPC` = "1",
  ) |> 
  req_perform()
```